# Add YAML validation file in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, validation, annotations

How can I add a file in `/config/validation.yaml` as a mapping validation **in order to avoid using annotations** in my DTOs?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to edit the `config/validator/validation.yaml` file instead?

Comment: I've moved validation.yaml to "config/validator" folder and apparently It didn't work. It's this a default configuration?

Comment: according to [official docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html), yes, it is

Comment: Its seems I did something wrong when I tried this solution first. I did it again, and it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is quite simple.

Just add in validator.yaml file the following:

```
framework:
    validation:
        email_validation_mode: html5
        mapping:
          paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/src/<path to validation file>'
```

Comment: Not sure if this means that you resolved the issue or not?